# How to upload a mp3 file upto 5 mb size on webserver in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, web-services

I want to upload an audio file from my iPhone app to webserver but when I convert it into NSData then it will take upto 30 to 40 min in conversion, so can you gave any better solution for it.

Comment: What's the size of audio file that you want to upload? I'm conversing approx. 22MB audio file to NSData and it does not taking such a big time for conversion. Please post your code of conversion too.

Comment: NSString *file1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"background" ofType:@"mp3"];
 NSData *file1Data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:file1];     The size of background.mp3 file is just 4.2 mb and it will take approx 30 to 40 min in conversion.

Answer (score 2):

1).To convert audio file to NSData:

```
NSString *audioFilePath = @""; // local path where audio stored
NSData *audioData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:audioFilePath];
```

2).To upload audio file:

```
NSString *audioName = @"myAudio.caf";
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someurl.aspx"]];    
[request addData:audioData withFileName:audioName andContentType:@"audio/caf" forKey:@"audioFile"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:500];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFinished:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFailed:)];
[request startAsynchronous];

- (void)uploadRequestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;   
    NSData *webData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[request responseData]];
    NSString *strEr =  [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

- (void) uploadRequestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSLog(@"responseStatusCode %i",[request responseStatusCode]);
    NSLog(@"responseString %@",[request responseString]);
    NSError *error = [request error];
    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. But I am working on xcode 4.2 and IOS 5 and there are I am facing lot of file missing or framework. Can you attach the source code zip file.

Comment: Above code is working perfect with Xcode 4.2 & IOS 5. You might not be having ASIHTTP helper files, you can download it from, https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/tree.

Comment: Thanks for reply and support. But when I convert audio file to NSData through your code then it again take long time to convert. There are any other alternate except nsdata to send iur audio file on server quickly.

Comment: Can you please confirm, is it taking long time to convert or to upload on server?

Comment: I have used just these two line "NSString *audioFilePath = @"background.mp3";
NSData *audioData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:audioFilePath];" and when I nslog the audioData then it will take so much time.

Comment: Remove NSLog to print NSData, it causes the long time consumption while printing log. As you are converting a big file so it will definitely having so many converted data and to print them takes more time.

Comment: Thanks alot ....you have saved my lot of time...I have passed my 3 days for it. Thanks again.

Comment: If my given solution has worked for you,the answer should be given accepted rate.

Comment: Yes please, I will if its in my hand...:)

Comment: Hello. I have 3 class with 3 view controller. And I am adding Second view as a subview in my First View. and In second view there are a button and I want that when I click on that button the third view is added on first view as a subview. But my application is crash when I click on that button. Can you help that how I'll perform any event in subview.

Comment: Hello. I am using sqlite database in my app. When I run the application from simulator then I am able to see the result in firefox sqlite plugin in my .sqlite file. But when I run on real device then I am not able to see the result so can you tell me how can I see the result and from where I can get that sqlite file.

Comment: Its a totally different post than titled question, so you should start a new question or at least try to find it out on site. Its already asked question. Check it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175687/how-to-export-sqlite-database-file-from-iphone-to-mac

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the link is not helpful for me. I am asking that how I'll see my database that row is insert or not in it when I run app on my iPhone device. And for see the result of database I am using firefox sqlite plugin.

Comment: Either by debugging or after completion of insertion you have to use mentioned application and download sqlite and then you are able to check database status. Check video, http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=t-CPeDLlUNQ

Comment: Hello...I am starting to make an iPhone chat application where the users can do private chat.So can you gave any idea, or any running application, or any code to that. Thanks.

Comment: @SKMAISM I'll surely try to help you. It would be better to start a new question while you are having a new query other than the posted question. Post your query & inform me.

Comment: Hello..I have post my question "How to do private chat in iPhone?" . Please help.

Comment: Hello..I have post my question "How to get response from server in iphone chat application?" Please help.

Comment: how to get NSData of mp3 using MPMediaPickerController?