# How to upload video to ASP.NET in Xcode?

Tags: asp.net, objective-c, xcode

I've haven't seen any post related to uploading video from iPhone (Xcode) to ASP.NET, so far only Facebook and Youtube and PHP.

I've followed one example of uploading video but to php (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zqRnnwFpRqk)

but somehow it doesn't work.
The file reached the ASP.NET side as with just the headers, no video content. I can open up and see the file with the post header with a text editor.

What could be wrong?

```
NSCharacterSet *mov = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@".MOV"];
self.mediaPath = [self.mediaPath stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:mov];
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:self.mediaPath ofType:@"MOV"]];
NSString *urlString = @"http://mysite.com/mobileupload.aspx";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641500";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
NSString *platformType = kMETRO_PLATFORM_TYPE_IOS;
[request addValue:platformType forHTTPHeaderField:@"SD-Platform"];
mediaType = kTYPE_VIDEO;
[request addValue:mediaType forHTTPHeaderField:@"SD-Category"];
videoFilename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [self GenerateUuid], @".mov"];
[request addValue:videoFilename forHTTPHeaderField:@"SD-Filename"];
self.mediaPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", kVIDEOS_URL, videoFilename];
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", videoFilename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:videoData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

In the ASP.NET code behind, here's what I have

```
string uploadPath = "~/upload/";
HttpFileCollection fileCollection = Request.Files;
fileCollection[0].SaveAs(Server.MapPath(uploadPath + fileCollection[0].FileName]);
```

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share a link which will help you to find out better solution. Given link has code to upload an audio on .net server but it will work same to upload video with minor modification.

You can found rest of the code at
[How to upload a mp3 file upto 5 mb size on webserver in iPhone.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11862693/790794)

To upload audio:

```
[request addData:audioData withFileName:audioName andContentType:@"audio/caf" forKey:@"audioFile"];
```

To upload video:

```
[request addData:audioData withFileName:videoName andContentType:@"video/mov" forKey:@"videoFile"];
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try to have a look on the link provided. Tq

Comment: Hi iApple, what does the forKey:@"videoFile" do?? Is there something that I can do about it on ASP.NET code?

Comment: Yes, you can use that key on ASP.Net code if you use a form in the website. You just create the form fields in the website and reference them when you create the request.

Comment: I find it rather strange that the content-length of the video file I upload is 0. Is there anyway that I can determine that I have selected the correct video file with a size?

Comment: To upload a video, which server are you using?

Comment: The video will be uploaded to a IIS 7. However, now I discovered that my video that is assigned to NSData appears to have zero length.

NSLog(@"%@", self.mediaPath);// yields:- /private/var/mobile/Applications/22318D96-B5B5-4C92-A8EB-869311275E40/tmp//trim.KlsIub.MOV
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:self.mediaPath ofType:@"mov"]];
int dataSize = [videoData length]; // yields: datasize: 0

something seems to be wrong here..
NSLog(@"datasize: %d", dataSize);

Comment: You need to verify wether video exists at given path and also check that self.mediaPath contains correct location. Due to not getting valid location NSData might not able to read content of the file.

Comment: Hi iApple, if i have a line like the following:
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Movie" ofType:@"mov"]];
in which there is a Movie.mov file attached to the project solution, then the movie can be uploaded. However, when I check the self.mediaPath, it returns back a string path like example
/private/var/mobile/Applications/22318D96-B5B5-4C92-A8EB-869311275E40/tmp//trim.AE6xnl.MOV
QUESTION: is the name of the movie that got compressed 'trim.AE6xnl.MOV' ??

Comment: I guess, name of the video ("trim.‌​AE6xnl.MOV") might be creating problem to convert into NSData