# how to upload the audio songs into server using ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, mpmediapickercontroller

I am beginner iOS apps developer .I have tried following link codes.It's playing good but I need selected audio file path and how to upload to server in selected audio,kindly help out.[Audio code Reference url](http://oleb.net/blog/2009/07/the-music-player-framework-in-the-iphone-sdk/)

```
    -(IBAction)clickFileuploadbtn:(id)sender;
{
    NSLog(@"2");
    picker1 =
    [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeMusic];

    picker1.delegate      = self;
    picker1.allowsPickingMultipleItems = YES;
    picker1.prompt      = NSLocalizedString (@"Add songs to play", "Prompt in media item picker");

    // The media item picker uses the default UI style, so it needs a default-style
    //  status bar to match it visually
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleDefault animated: YES];

    [self presentModalViewController: picker1 animated: YES];
    [picker1 release];
    // [Uploads FileUpload];
}
- (void)mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection
{


    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];

    NSLog(@"%@ %d",mediaItemCollection,mediaItemCollection.count);

    NSArray *newMediaItem= [mediaItemCollection items];


    MPMediaItem *item=[[newMediaItem objectAtIndex:0] retain];

    [self uploadMusicFile:item];
}
- (void)mediaPickerDidCancel:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];

    NSLog(@"cancel");

}


- (void) uploadMusicFile:(MPMediaItem *)song
{
    NSURL *url = [song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];

    // Given some file path URL: NSURL *pathURL
    // Note: [pathURL isFileURL] must return YES
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url];
    NSLog(@"path %@",path);
    NSData *data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:path];
    NSLog(@"data %@" ,data);
    NSString *audioName = @"myAudio.caf";
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.176:1001/api?type=iphoneupload"]];
    [request addData:data withFileName:audioName andContentType:@"audio/caf" forKey:@"audioFile"];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setTimeOutSeconds:500];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFinished:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFailed:)];
    [request startAsynchronous];



}

- (void)uploadRequestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    NSData *webData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[request responseData]];
    NSString *strEr =  [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"strEr %@",strEr);
}

- (void) uploadRequestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSLog(@"responseStatusCode %i",[request responseStatusCode]);
    NSLog(@"responseString %@",[request responseString]);
    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(@"error %@",error);
    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}
```

Comment: try this :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862273/how-to-upload-a-mp3-file-upto-5-mb-size-on-webserver-in-iphone

Comment: i am not able to see your code. can you paste it some other website?

Comment: can you see that codes. http://paste.org/62055

Comment: NSData *data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:path];    here data is null

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195460/how-to-get-nsdata-of-mp3-using-mpmediapickercontroller

Comment: Have you got any solution ?