# How to get NSData of mp3 using MPMediaPickerController?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary, mpmediapickercontroller

I want to upload mp3 from my phone to server, for this i am using `MPMediaPickerController`.

After getting URL of `MPMediaItem`, i want to get NSData of this url , but i am getting null in NSData.

```
- (void) mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker didPickMediaItems: (MPMediaItemCollection *) mediaItemCollection
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    MPMediaItem *item=[[mediaItemCollection items] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSURL *url = [item valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url];
    NSData *data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:path];
}
```

i also tried

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

But data is null, why?

I also tried [NOt able to convert from MPMediaItem(mp3 song) to NSData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15039578/not-able-to-convert-from-mpmediaitemmp3-song-to-nsdata) But not getting result.

Can any one guide me to get NSData of mp3.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you need to know what was the reason for failure, use dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:.

Comment: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)" UserInfo=0x1cd051b0 {NSURL=ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=-4848947984816581540}

Comment: The URL is only appropriate w/ AVFoundation; NSData won't be able to do a thing w/ the NSURL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this library: https://github.com/tapsquare/TSLibraryImport It can convert non-DRM items from iPod music library to mp3 files and then you can save them or use as NSData for further processing.

Comment: Can you please tell that if i want to convert it into NSData what should i need to do? Currently i am using 

NSMutableData *outputData = [[NSMutableData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:outURL];

But it is not playing at server end . Please help if possible .

Thanks in Advance