# How to POST an audio file via NSURLConnection iPhone?

Tags: iphone, web-services, nsurlconnection, nsmutableurlrequest

I tried a dozen things. But am not receiving results. I want to convert an audio file wav/mp3 to byte array or otherwise and send it to a php server. Following are few things i tried that are already listed in SO. please help.

```
 NSURL *urlPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"r2d2" ofType:@"mp3"]];
NSString *wavbundlepath = [urlPath absoluteString];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:wavbundlepath]];


NSUInteger len = data.length;
int8_t *bytes = (int8_t *)[data bytes];
NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:len];
[result appendString:@"["];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (i) {
        [result appendString:@","];
    }
    [result appendFormat:@"%d", bytes[i]];
}
[result appendString:@"]"];

NSString *urlString = @"http://apps2.mobiiworld.com/staging/krafttesting/";

// setting up the request object now
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSData* dataSend = [result dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody:dataSend];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData *responseData2 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
NSLog(@"responseData: %@", responseData2);
```

next

```
NSURL *urlPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"r2d2" ofType:@"mp3"]];
NSString *wavbundlepath = [urlPath absoluteString];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:wavbundlepath]];NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

/*
 add some header info now
 we always need a boundary when we post a file
 also we need to set the content type

 You might want to generate a random boundary.. this is just the same
 as my output from wireshark on a valid html post
 */
NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

/*
 now lets create the body of the post
 */

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSString *filename = @"file";
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\";filename=\"%@\"\r\n", filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
//  NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\";filename=\"%@\"\r\n", filename]);
//[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"test"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
//[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// now lets make the connection to the web
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Return :    %@", returnString);
```

The php developer says that he is not receiving any data whatsoever. And he has echoed whatever he receives, but i find a Null string in response. Can anyone please suggest what to do?

Comment: may be this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195460/how-to-get-nsdata-of-mp3-using-mpmediapickercontroller

Comment: Thanks Rajneesh but i am receiving NSData value. I am not able to upload it to the server.

Comment: you have to convert NSData into base64 endoding and said your server side developer to use base64 decoding..

Comment: There should be no need to base64 encode it, that would just be a waste of bandwidth.

Comment: The php developer says that he is not receiving any data whatsoever. And he has echoed whatever he receives, but i find a Null string in response. Can anyone please suggest what to do?

Comment: @ScarletWitch you can try ASIHTTPRequest also

Answer (score -1):

This is how i am doing it

```
NSData *audioData = Here comes your NSData;
NSString *urlString = @"The url of php file";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".caf\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:audioData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSLog(@"Length : %d", returnData.length);
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Return String %@", returnString);
```

---

There is another way via ASIHTTPRequest

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"the url comes here"];
ASIFormDataRequest *formRequest = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([self scaleAndRotateImage:self.m_ImageViewProfile.image], 90);

NSLog(@"Size : %d", imageData.length);

[formRequest setTimeOutSeconds:600];
[formRequest setPostValue:@"If there is any"] forKey:@"the key"];
[formRequest setData:imageData withFileName:@"myphoto.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"filename"];

//[formRequest setUploadProgressDelegate:progressView];

[formRequest setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSString *responseString = [formRequest responseString];
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseString);
}];
[formRequest setFailedBlock:^{
    NSError *error = [formRequest error];
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];

[formRequest startSynchronous];
```

See if it is what you want

Comment: That is useful when posting multiple data streams. When just posting one simple file, it is probably easier to skip the multipart header (depending on how it works on the PHP side, I have no clue as I am stuck in the Python/Django world :) )