# Get access to media from iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I need to access media files(Audio and video) and upload to server.I'm able to get media library using `MPMediaPickerController` but did not get any clue how to get data (`NSData` ?) so that i can send it to server?

**Edit**: I'v searched for the same [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396319/fetch-all-audio-video-files-in-ios) suggest to read [iPod library access](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/AboutiPodLibraryAccess/AboutiPodLibraryAccess.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765-CH103-SW9) any one one some tutorial/sample code for the same?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get NSData of mp3 using MPMediaPickerController?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195460/how-to-get-nsdata-of-mp3-using-mpmediapickercontroller)

Comment: Third-party libraries? I also found this thread useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656124/mpmediaitems-raw-song-data