# Can I upload an MP3 file to my server from iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I was googling this question but nothing useful or current came up. I'd like to know if (and if, how) you can select an MP3 file (from itunes?) and upload the contents to one of my own servers on iOS (iphone & ipad app).

One of my clients is asking me if it's possible to do this, and I havn't found the answer yet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862273/how-to-upload-a-mp3-file-upto-5-mb-size-on-webserver-in-iphone]

Comment: You can retrieve the "file content" of a music from Music.app in your own application. You may have to use `AVAssetExportSession` (or something like that, go look at AudioVideo.framework), and you can also send large file to a server. There are samples/related question in SO for the two cases (separately).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer would be YES.

Here is a working solution for me. But you need to use a [third party library](https://github.com/tapsquare/TSLibraryImport). Then this is what you need to do:

1. Create a temp folder either in the NSDocuments directory or a temp directory.
2. Use `MPMediaQuery` to load the music files.
3. The object that you will get from the `MPMediaQuery` is an `MPMediaItem`. With this you can get the asset URL of the media item.

Code:

```
NSString *assetURL = [mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
```

get the extension of with the asset URL

```
NSString *extension = [TSLibraryImport extensionForAssetURL:assetURL];
```

set a location URL (This will be the location where the mp3 music data will be imported).

```
NSString *locationURL = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:musicTitleYouWant]] URLByAppendingPathExtension:extension];
```

Now you can import the contents of the mp3 from to the directory you set earlier.

```
TSLibraryImport *libraryImport = [[TSLibraryImport alloc] init];

[libraryImport importAsset:assetURL toURL:locationURL completionBlock:^(TSLibraryImport *libraryImport)
{
    if(libraryImport.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted)
    {
         //Once complete the file will be store on the location URL you set earlier. Now you can get the file from that location and convert it to NSData and send it to the server. There are plenty of ways to do that.
     }

     else
     {
         //Here means import failed. :(
     }
}];
```

Hope this helps. :)